# Displaying user's first name in a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying to display the first name value for a user in a jsp page. All users have getters and setters for each of their attributes. Here's the code :

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.user.getF_name()}" default="guest" />
```

However, I'm getting the error :

```
/index.jsp(77,4) The function getF_name must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.user.f_name}" default="guest" />
```

you need to specify the  bean property instead of method when using EL.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call the getter, it would be called by the EL, so you just have to use

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.user.f_name}" default="guest" />
```

Or even easier, just let the EL takes care about searching the `user` attribute in session scope for you.

```
<c:out value="${user.f_name}" default="guest" />
```

Note that for the latter to work you must have a `user` attribute in session scope **only**.

You can find more info about this on [StackOverflow EL wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).